# Uncaught SyntexError: Unexpected end of input JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm getting on chrome Uncaught SyntexError: Unexpected end of input in the first line of code I went through my code but I cannot find it please help me.
I searched through treads here but noting.
What do I need to do in order to fix it?

```
<%--JS--%>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var is_chrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        try {
            if (is_chrome) {
                //alert("is chrome!!");
                $("span#spanAddPerson").css("top", "0px");
            }

        } catch (err) {
            alert(err);
        }
    });



</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setClientTime(sender, eventArgs) {
        try {
            var datePicker = $find("<%= actOverViewDateTime.ClientID %>");
            var date = datePicker.get_selectedDate();
            if (date == null) {
                var nowDate = new Date();
                datePicker.set_selectedDate(nowDate);
            }
        } catch (err) {
            alert(err);
        }
    }

    function StatusCheck(sender, args) {
        var status = $find("<%= rcbStatus.ClientID %>");
        var datePickerEndingTime = $find("<%= rdtpEndingTime.ClientID %>");
        var item = status.get_text();
        if (item == "Closed") {
            document.getElementById('EndingTime').style.visibility = 'visible'
            datePickerEndingTime.set_visible(true);
            var nowDate = new Date();
            datePickerEndingTime.set_selectedDate(nowDate)
            datePickerEndingTime.set_maxDate(nowDate);

        } else {
            document.getElementById('EndingTime').style.visibility = 'hidden'
            datePickerEndingTime.set_visible(false);
        }
    }

    //IE7 bug
    // Only Numeric keys and "."-(46) are allowed
    function isNumberKey(e, allowDecimalPoint) {
        var key = e.charCode || e.keyCode || 0;
        var keychar = String.fromCharCode(key);
        if (!allowDecimalPoint && key == 46) e.preventDefault();
        if (((key == 8 || key == 9 || key == 46 || key == 35 || key == 36 || (key >= 37 && key <= 40)) && e.charCode == 0) /* backspace, end, begin, top, bottom, right, left, del, tab */
            || (key >= 46 && key <= 57)) { /* 0-9 */
            return;
        } else {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }

    function abc(sender) {
        var radTextBox1 = $find("actOverViewCode");
        radTextBox1.get_styles().EnabledStyle[0] = "background-color: LightYellow;";
        radTextBox1.updateCssClass();
    }

    function NumbersOnly(sender, args) {
        var keycode = args.get_keyCode()
        if (keycode == 8) {
            //Checking if the key pressed is BackSpace key, then do not cancel the event.
            return;
        }
        if (keycode != 46 && keycode != 45 && keycode > 31 && (keycode < 48 || keycode > 57)) {
            args.set_cancel(true);
        }

    }

    function getDateTime() {
        var now = new Date();
        var year = now.getFullYear();
        var month = now.getMonth() + 1;
        var day = now.getDate();
        var hour = now.getHours();
        var minute = now.getMinutes();
        var second = now.getSeconds();
        if (month.toString().length == 1) {
            var month = '0' + month;
        }
        if (day.toString().length == 1) {
            var day = '0' + day;
        }
        if (hour.toString().length == 1) {
            var hour = '0' + hour;
        }
        if (minute.toString().length == 1) {
            var minute = '0' + minute;
        }
        if (second.toString().length == 1) {
            var second = '0' + second;
        }
        var dateTime = year + '/' + month + '/' + day + ' ' + hour + ':' + minute + ':' + second;
        return dateTime;
    }

    function checkLevelZone(sender, args) {
        var txtOffSite = $find("<%=txtOffSite.ClientID %>");
        var checkbox = $find("<%=cbIsOffSite.ClientID %>");
        var level = $find("<%=ActOverviewLevel.ClientID %>");
        var zone = $find("<%=ActOverViewZone.ClientID %>");

        if (checkbox.get_checked()) {
            level.clearSelection();
            zone.clearSelection();
            level.trackChanges();
            zone.trackChanges();
            level.disable();
            zone.disable();
            txtOffSite.enable();
        } else {
            level.enable();
            //zone.enable();
            txtOffSite.disable();
        }
    }

    function CheckPersonLocation(sender, args) {
        var l_location = $find("<%=rcbPeopleLocation.ClientID %>");
        var count = l_location.get_checkedItems().length;
        if (count <= 1) {
            radconfirm('Would you like to add more location to that person?</br>', confirmDisableCallBackFn, 370, 200, null, 'Case Global Alert');
        } else {
            __doPostBack("<%=btnAddPerson.UniqueID %>", "");
        }
    }
    function confirmDisableCallBackFn(arg) {
        if (arg == true) {
            check.set_checked(false);
            __doPostBack("<%=btnAddPerson.UniqueID %>", "");
        }
        else {
            check.set_checked(true);
        }
    }
    function togglePopupModality() {
        var wnd = $find("<%=modalPopup.ClientID %>");
        wnd.set_modal(!wnd.get_modal());
        if (!wnd.get_modal()) document.documentElement.focus();
    }

    function showDialogInitially() {
        var wnd = $find("<%=modalPopup.ClientID %>");
        wnd.show();
        Sys.Application.remove_load(showDialogInitially);
    }

    function disableSubmitButton(sender, eventArgs) {
        $find("<%=btnAddActivity.ClientID %>").set_enabled(false);
        __doPostBack("<%=btnAddActivity.UniqueID %>", "");
    }

    function confirmPersonDuplicateCallBackFn(arg) {
        if (arg == true) {
            $get("<%=hfCheckDuplicate.ClientID %>").value = "0";
            __doPostBack("<%=btnAddPerson.UniqueID %>", "");
        }
    }
    function DisableSaving(sender, args) {
        var isValid = Page_ClientValidate('validationOverviewTab');
        if (isValid) {
            var rcbStatus = $find("<%=rcbStatus.ClientID %>");
            if (rcbStatus.get_text() == "Open") {
                sender.set_autoPostBack(true);
            } else {
                var OverViewDateTime = $find("<%=actOverViewDateTime.ClientID %>");
                var getOverViewDateTime = OverViewDateTime.get_selectedDate();
                var date = new Date(getOverViewDateTime), mnth = ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2), day = ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
                var resultOverViewDate = [mnth, day, date.getFullYear()].join("-");
                var getOverViewHours = getOverViewDateTime.getHours();
                var getOverViewMin = getOverViewDateTime.getMinutes();
                var EndingDateTime = $find("<%=rdtpEndingTime.ClientID %>");
                var getEndingDateTime = EndingDateTime.get_selectedDate();
                var EndDate = new Date(getEndingDateTime), mnth = ("0" + (getEndingDateTime.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2), day = ("0" + getEndingDateTime.getDate()).slice(-2);
                var resultEndingDate = [mnth, day, date.getFullYear()].join("-");
                var getEndingHours = getEndingDateTime.getHours();
                var getEndingMin = getEndingDateTime.getMinutes();
                //Check for Valid Dates
                if (resultOverViewDate > resultEndingDate) {
                    radalert("Date/Time is greater than Ending Time Please correct date and time<h3 style='color: #ff0000;'></h3>", 380, 170, "Alert");
                } else if (resultOverViewDate < resultEndingDate) {
                    sender.set_autoPostBack(true);
                }
                if (resultOverViewDate == resultEndingDate) {
                    //Check if it's the case of equal hours
                    if (getOverViewHours == getEndingHours) {
                        if (getOverViewMin > getEndingMin) {
                            radalert("Date/Time-minutes must be less then Ending Time-minutes<h3 style='color: #ff0000;'></h3>", 380, 170, "Alert");
                        } else if (getOverViewHours == getEndingHours && getOverViewMin == getEndingMin) {
                            sender.set_autoPostBack(true);
                        }
                        else {
                            sender.set_autoPostBack(true);
                        }
                    } else {
                        sender.set_autoPostBack(true);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function SaveStatus(sender, args) {
        var status = $find("<%= rcbStatus.ClientID %>");
        var datePickerEndingTime = $find("<%= rdtpEndingTime.ClientID %>");
        var item = status.get_text();
        if (item == "Closed") {
            document.getElementById('EndingTime').style.visibility = 'visible'
            datePickerEndingTime.set_visible(true);
        } else {
            document.getElementById('EndingTime').style.visibility = 'hidden'
            datePickerEndingTime.set_visible(false);
        }
}
```

Comment: what does `<%--JS--%>`do ? if you want that as a comment, use `<%//JS--%>`

Comment: I took it out and still I have the same problem

Comment: just a guess, try removing the comments inside the `isNumberKey` function

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare is_chrome in try block and end your script tag,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    try {
        var is_chrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;
        if (is_chrome) {
            //alert("is chrome!!");
            $("span#spanAddPerson").css({'top': "0px"});//top syntax is like this.
        }

    } catch (err) {
        alert(err);
    }
});

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function setClientTime(sender, eventArgs) {
    try {
        var datePicker = $find("<%= actOverViewDateTime.ClientID %>");
        var date = datePicker.get_selectedDate();
        if (date == null) {
            var nowDate = new Date();
            datePicker.set_selectedDate(nowDate);
        }
    } catch (err) {
        alert(err);
    }
}

function StatusCheck(sender, args) {
    var status = $find("<%= rcbStatus.ClientID %>");
    var datePickerEndingTime = $find("<%= rdtpEndingTime.ClientID %>");
    var item = status.get_text();
    if (item == "Closed") {
        document.getElementById('EndingTime').style.visibility = 'visible'
        datePickerEndingTime.set_visible(true);
        var nowDate = new Date();
        datePickerEndingTime.set_selectedDate(nowDate)
        datePickerEndingTime.set_maxDate(nowDate);

    } else {
        document.getElementById('EndingTime').style.visibility = 'hidden'
        datePickerEndingTime.set_visible(false);
    }
}

//IE7 bug
// Only Numeric keys and "."-(46) are allowed
function isNumberKey(e, allowDecimalPoint) {
    var key = e.charCode || e.keyCode || 0;
    var keychar = String.fromCharCode(key);
    if (!allowDecimalPoint && key == 46) e.preventDefault();
    if (((key == 8 || key == 9 || key == 46 || key == 35 || key == 36 || (key >= 37 && key <= 40)) && e.charCode == 0) /* backspace, end, begin, top, bottom, right, left, del, tab */
        || (key >= 46 && key <= 57)) { /* 0-9 */
        return;
    } else {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}

function abc(sender) {
    var radTextBox1 = $find("actOverViewCode");
    radTextBox1.get_styles().EnabledStyle[0] = "background-color: LightYellow;";
    radTextBox1.updateCssClass();
}

function NumbersOnly(sender, args) {
    var keycode = args.get_keyCode()
    if (keycode == 8) {
        //Checking if the key pressed is BackSpace key, then do not cancel the event.
        return;
    }
    if (keycode != 46 && keycode != 45 && keycode > 31 && (keycode < 48 || keycode > 57)) {
        args.set_cancel(true);
    }

}

function getDateTime() {
    var now = new Date();
    var year = now.getFullYear();
    var month = now.getMonth() + 1;
    var day = now.getDate();
    var hour = now.getHours();
    var minute = now.getMinutes();
    var second = now.getSeconds();
    if (month.toString().length == 1) {
        var month = '0' + month;
    }
    if (day.toString().length == 1) {
        var day = '0' + day;
    }
    if (hour.toString().length == 1) {
        var hour = '0' + hour;
    }
    if (minute.toString().length == 1) {
        var minute = '0' + minute;
    }
    if (second.toString().length == 1) {
        var second = '0' + second;
    }
    var dateTime = year + '/' + month + '/' + day + ' ' + hour + ':' + minute + ':' + second;
    return dateTime;
}

function checkLevelZone(sender, args) {
    var txtOffSite = $find("<%=txtOffSite.ClientID %>");
    var checkbox = $find("<%=cbIsOffSite.ClientID %>");
    var level = $find("<%=ActOverviewLevel.ClientID %>");
    var zone = $find("<%=ActOverViewZone.ClientID %>");

    if (checkbox.get_checked()) {
        level.clearSelection();
        zone.clearSelection();
        level.trackChanges();
        zone.trackChanges();
        level.disable();
        zone.disable();
        txtOffSite.enable();
    } else {
        level.enable();
        //zone.enable();
        txtOffSite.disable();
    }
}

function CheckPersonLocation(sender, args) {
    var l_location = $find("<%=rcbPeopleLocation.ClientID %>");
    var count = l_location.get_checkedItems().length;
    if (count <= 1) {
        radconfirm('Would you like to add more location to that person?</br>', confirmDisableCallBackFn, 370, 200, null, 'Case Global Alert');
    } else {
        __doPostBack("<%=btnAddPerson.UniqueID %>", "");
    }
}
function confirmDisableCallBackFn(arg) {
    if (arg == true) {
        check.set_checked(false);
        __doPostBack("<%=btnAddPerson.UniqueID %>", "");
    }
    else {
        check.set_checked(true);
    }
}
function togglePopupModality() {
    var wnd = $find("<%=modalPopup.ClientID %>");
    wnd.set_modal(!wnd.get_modal());
    if (!wnd.get_modal()) document.documentElement.focus();
}

function showDialogInitially() {
    var wnd = $find("<%=modalPopup.ClientID %>");
    wnd.show();
    Sys.Application.remove_load(showDialogInitially);
}

function disableSubmitButton(sender, eventArgs) {
    $find("<%=btnAddActivity.ClientID %>").set_enabled(false);
    __doPostBack("<%=btnAddActivity.UniqueID %>", "");
}

function confirmPersonDuplicateCallBackFn(arg) {
    if (arg == true) {
        $get("<%=hfCheckDuplicate.ClientID %>").value = "0";
        __doPostBack("<%=btnAddPerson.UniqueID %>", "");
    }
}
function DisableSaving(sender, args) {
    var isValid = Page_ClientValidate('validationOverviewTab');
    if (isValid) {
        var rcbStatus = $find("<%=rcbStatus.ClientID %>");
        if (rcbStatus.get_text() == "Open") {
            sender.set_autoPostBack(true);
        } else {
            var OverViewDateTime = $find("<%=actOverViewDateTime.ClientID %>");
            var getOverViewDateTime = OverViewDateTime.get_selectedDate();
            var date = new Date(getOverViewDateTime), mnth = ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2), day = ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
            var resultOverViewDate = [mnth, day, date.getFullYear()].join("-");
            var getOverViewHours = getOverViewDateTime.getHours();
            var getOverViewMin = getOverViewDateTime.getMinutes();
            var EndingDateTime = $find("<%=rdtpEndingTime.ClientID %>");
            var getEndingDateTime = EndingDateTime.get_selectedDate();
            var EndDate = new Date(getEndingDateTime), mnth = ("0" + (getEndingDateTime.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2), day = ("0" + getEndingDateTime.getDate()).slice(-2);
            var resultEndingDate = [mnth, day, date.getFullYear()].join("-");
            var getEndingHours = getEndingDateTime.getHours();
            var getEndingMin = getEndingDateTime.getMinutes();
            //Check for Valid Dates
            if (resultOverViewDate > resultEndingDate) {
                radalert("Date/Time is greater than Ending Time Please correct date and time<h3 style='color: #ff0000;'></h3>", 380, 170, "Alert");
            } else if (resultOverViewDate < resultEndingDate) {
                sender.set_autoPostBack(true);
            }
            if (resultOverViewDate == resultEndingDate) {
                //Check if it's the case of equal hours
                if (getOverViewHours == getEndingHours) {
                    if (getOverViewMin > getEndingMin) {
                        radalert("Date/Time-minutes must be less then Ending Time-minutes<h3 style='color: #ff0000;'></h3>", 380, 170, "Alert");
                    } else if (getOverViewHours == getEndingHours && getOverViewMin == getEndingMin) {
                        sender.set_autoPostBack(true);
                    }
                    else {
                        sender.set_autoPostBack(true);
                    }
                } else {
                    sender.set_autoPostBack(true);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

function SaveStatus(sender, args) {
    var status = $find("<%= rcbStatus.ClientID %>");
    var datePickerEndingTime = $find("<%= rdtpEndingTime.ClientID %>");
    var item = status.get_text();
    if (item == "Closed") {
        document.getElementById('EndingTime').style.visibility = 'visible'
        datePickerEndingTime.set_visible(true);
    } else {
        document.getElementById('EndingTime').style.visibility = 'hidden'
        datePickerEndingTime.set_visible(false);
    }
   }
 </script>
```